# How can write like this picture in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

Any idea how can we do that in beamer?
Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: That should not be so difficult with TikZ, except for the background picure! And remember this is not "please do that for me" website: what have you tried so far?

Comment: If i could do it dear i wouldn't ask. So please kindley if you do not want to help just skip, thanks.

Comment: @Angelina Maria, you say you can't do it but quite obviously you haven't even tried. NBur is right to ask you to make some effort first and then ask where you are stuck.

Comment: And you asked "How can I do…" Thus I answered "with TikZ"…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (condensed) solution with a `foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (L0) at (0, 0);
    \foreach \lettre/\couleur/\texte/\ancre [count=\li, evaluate={\lj=\li-1}] in {
        M/red/Matrix theory/130, A/Gold1/Algebra/90, T/Green3/Trigonometry/130,
        H/Cyan1/Hilbert space/120, E/HotPink1/Ergodicity/90, M/black/{Measure\\ theory}/90,
        A/HotPink1/Analysis/90, T/Cyan1/Topology/80, I/Green3/Integration/80,
        C/Gold1/{Complex\\ number}/80, S/red/Set theory/80
    }
    {
        \node (L\li) [right=2ex of L\lj]  {\lettre};
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{-abs(\li-6)*.5-1};
        \path [draw=\couleur, line width=1.5pt, fill=\couleur] (L\li.south) --++(0, \y cm)
            circle [radius=2pt] node[anchor=\ancre, \couleur, align=center, font={\tiny\sffamily}] {\texte};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't say thanks enough, have a nice day, you saved my project. God bless you!

Answer (score 5):

[image: Mathematics]

Hard-coded example, to allow easy changes (color, positioning, fonts, etc). It also illustrates the Gauss-pairings quite well. Coding could be more compact and elegant, e.g., use of styles.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=3mm,row sep=4mm]
{
\node (L1) {\Large M}; &
\node (L2){\Large A}; &
\node (L3){\Large T}; &
\node (L4){\Large H}; &
\node (L5){\Large E}; &
\node (L6){\Large M}; &
\node (L7){\Large A}; &
\node (L8){\Large T}; &
\node (L9){\Large I}; &
\node (L10){\Large C}; &
\node (L11){\Large S}; 
 \\
%
&&&&&&&&&&&
\\
%
&&&&&\node (blank1){} ; &&&&&&
\\
%
&&&&& \node (c6)[circle,fill=black]{} ; 
&&
 & & & &
\\
%
&&&& \node (c5)[circle,fill=pink]{} ; 
&&
\node (c7)[circle,fill=pink]{} ; & & & & &
\\
%
&&& \node (c4)[circle,fill=blue]{} ; 
&&&&
\node (c8)[circle,fill=blue]{} ; & & & &
\\
%
&& \node (c3)[circle,fill=green]{} ; 
&&&&&&
\node (c9)[circle,fill=green]{} ; & & &
\\
%
& \node (c2)[circle,fill=yellow]{} ; 
&&&&&&&&
\node (c10)[circle,fill=yellow]{} ; & &
\\
%
\node (c1)[circle,fill=red]{} ; &
&&&&&&&&&
\node (c11)[circle,fill=red]{} ; &
\\
};
%
\draw [thick,red] (c1) -- (L1);
\draw [thick,red] (c11) -- (L11);
%
\draw [thick,yellow] (c2) -- (L2);
\draw [thick,yellow] (c10) -- (L10);
%
\draw [thick,green] (c3) -- (L3);
\draw [thick,green] (c9) -- (L9);
%
\draw [thick,blue] (c4) -- (L4);
\draw [thick,blue] (c8) -- (L8);
%
\draw [thick,pink] (c5) -- (L5);
\draw [thick,pink] (c7) -- (L7);
%
\draw [thick,black] (c6) -- (L6);
%
\node (label1)[scale=0.75,below=of c1,yshift=13mm] {Matrix theory};
\node (label2)[scale=0.75,below=of c2,yshift=13mm] {Algebra};
\node (label3)[scale=0.75,below=of c3,yshift=13mm,xshift=1em] {Trigonometry};
\node (label4)[scale=0.75,below=of c4,yshift=13mm,xshift=1em] {Hilbert space};
\node (label5)[scale=0.75,below=of c5,yshift=13mm,xshift=1em] {Ergodicity};
\node (label6)[scale=0.75,below=of c6,yshift=13mm,align=center] {Measure\\ theory};
\node (label7)[scale=0.75,below=of c7,yshift=13mm] {Analysis};
\node (label8)[scale=0.75,below=of c8,yshift=13mm] {Topology};
\node (label9)[scale=0.75,below=of c9,yshift=13mm] {Integration};
\node (label10)[scale=0.75,below=of c10,yshift=13mm,align=right] {Complex\\ number};
\node (label11)[scale=0.75,below=of c11,yshift=13mm] {Set theory};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TikZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ), LaTeX's most powerful tool for creating graphic elements.

[This tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package) should help you get started.

Beamer is more geared towards creating presentation slides and to my knowledge, it won't be useful for creating complex graphics.

Comment: Sorry, but in the present version, it seems to be as useful, as the answer "You should learn LaTeX" for a LaTeX question.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to imply with your comment. Beamer is a LaTeX class for creating presentations. So if the user in question indicated she uses Beamer, I would assume she has knowledge of LaTeX. Secondly, TikZ is not LaTeX, but a helpful graphics tool to complement it. So learning LaTeX won't imply learning this tool.

Comment: Yes Tristan Oa Galea, you are right, i have already Latex knowledge and i know that Tikz is not Latex. 
I  was trying during 2 days to do something at least similar to this picture that i attached, but it doesn't work that is why i asked here for help, but it seems like everyone here is disturbed because of my question, so i am sorry if i bothered anyone, it wasn't my intention, have a nice day.

Comment: @AngelinaMaria, your question bothered nobody. We only want you to share what you already tried to see where you are stucked… That is the meaning of my first comment.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515705/i-need-a-mindmap-on-latex-that-have-children-that-begot-children  Using tikz mindmap in beamer frame.